# pip defaulting to global path instead of conda env

Tags: python, pip, path, anaconda, conda

I create a conda environment in my repository and activate it

```
conda env create --prefix ./env
conda activate ./env
```

I can see that `python` now correctly uses the conda `PATH`

```
which python
/Users/michaelmoreno/project/env/bin/python
```

However, `pip` is still using my global homebrew install

```
which pip
/opt/homebrew/bin/pip
```

I can run `python -m pip` to use the correct conda provided pip, but I'd prefer to be able to run `pip`.

Why is this? How can I fix it?